# Python script producing ERROR 999999 on clip function

Tags: python, arcgis, clip, in-memory-database, arcpy

I am trying to write a Python script that takes a folder of shapefiles, selects one of the features within one of the polygon shapefiles and creates a buffer on that feature. This feature is then used to clip all of the shape files within the folder. The shape files are then all reprojected and written to a geodatabase.

It works for the first shape file in the folder and produces the result that I want but when it iterates to the next shapefile it gets as far as the clip function then I get "ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Clip)". Here is the code:

```
#Import modules

import arcpy
import os

#Environment settings 

arcpy.env.workspace ="V://Sam//GIS//HämtningarData//fk_12.Sweref_99_TM.Shape//Shape"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
outFolder = "V://Sam//GIS//Personliga mappar//test//test.gdb"

NAME = "YSTAD"
ystadKod = "_1286"
counter = 0
kommuner = "V://Sam//GIS//HämtningarData//GSD_Fastighetskartor//GSD_Fastightskarta_skane_TM_160908//Shape//ak_12.shp"
ak_buf = "in_memory" + "//ak_buf"
date = "_20160908"

#Select Ystad and create 3km Buffer
#SQL Query
kommunQuery = '"KOMMUNNAMN"' + ' = ' + "'"+ NAME + "'"

# Make a feature layer of ystad that applies the SQL expression
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(kommuner, "ystadLayer",kommunQuery)

# Process: Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("ystadLayer", ak_buf, "3 Kilometers", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "", "GEODESIC")

#Iterate feature classes in folder    
FeatureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for featureClass in FeatureClassList:

# make new feature class name
if "_" in featureClass:
    parts= featureClass.split('_')
    name = parts [0]
    newName = name + ystadKod + date
    print newName

else:
    name = featureClass[:-4]
    newName = name + ystadKod + date
    print newName

outPath = "in_memory" + "//" + newName
print featureClass
print ak_buf
print outPath
arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClass, ak_buf, outPath)

# Describe the feature class and get its spatial reference   
desc = arcpy.Describe(outPath)
spatialRef = desc.spatialReference

if desc.spatialReference.Name == "Unknown":
    print ('skipped this fc due to undefined coordinate system: ' + newName)
else:
    print spatialRef.Name

    #create new file path
    Result = outFolder +"//" + newName
    #print outPath

    # Set output coordinate system
    outCS = arcpy.SpatialReference(3008)

    # run project tool
    arcpy.Project_management(outPath, Result, outCS)

    # check messages
    print(arcpy.GetMessages())
    arcpy.Delete_management (outPath)

    counter = counter +1
print counter
```

I have also tested reprojecting everything first and then clipping but ArcGIS doesn't allow the output of a reprojection to be saved "in_memory". I want to make the program self contained so that it can be used without saving intermediate files locally.

Update -The script works on polygon shapefiles with lots of features but as soon as it comes to a line or point shape file even if they don't include many features, the script fails. Any ideas?

Comment: There are many thousands of ArcPy Q&As on the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Do you mean that I posted in the wrong place or that the answer is in the other forum?

Comment: It is not wrong to post it here but I think your question is much more on-topic at GIS SE and thus more likely to be answered there, if not already.